# Matplotlib minimum tick distance

Tags: python, matplotlib, format

I am plotting data with matplotlib that has different amplitudes for a large number of periods. In some periods there is hardly any amplitude (e.g. 0.1 for a resolution of the data of 0.1). Thus, matplotlib creates ticks in a resolution that is finer that the data's actual resolution.

Is there a way to define a MINIMUM distance between the ticks?

As the data amplitude can be quite high, I cannot use the same fixed distance for all plots. I would like to keep the ticks chosen automatically except for periods, where they are finer than 0.1.

Here is a MWE for a period with low amplitude illustrating the problem:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
x = range(10)
y = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
```

resulting in this:

[image]

In this case I would like to only have the ticks at 0.1 and 0.2.

Comment: I'm not sure I have completely understood your question, but you can use `ax.set_yticks([0.1,0.2])` to just show these two ticks in the y-axis.

Comment: The problem is that I loop over many periods and some have a large range of values, where for example I only want a tick every full number. Ideally, I would like to keep the automatic choice and just say the minimum distance between two ticks should be 0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the difference between the minimum and maximum y values. Then if that difference is less than a certain number, create a list of ticks with 0.1 spacing, otherwise create ticks with 1 spacing.

For example:

```
x = range(10)
y = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1]

diff = max(y) - min(y)
if diff < 2:
    ticks = np.arange(min(y), max(y)+0.05, 0.1)
else:
    ticks = np.arange(min(y), max(y)+0.5, 1)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
```

Would give:

[image]

But using y data with larger range:

```
y = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.5,10,0.1]
```

Gives:

[image]